# Image Quality Issues with App Engine Image Processing (JAVA)

Tags: java, image, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to process and save a series of images to Google Cloud Storage and am running into serious image quality issues when resizing images with App Engine.

The original image always saves without any quality issues, but when resizing using ImageServiceFactory the image saves out extremely pixelated. I realize I should be buffering the input stream, but can't imagine that's effecting the image quality.

Is the ImageServiceFactory just garbage?

Thanks for the help!

Here's the code:

```
  public static void process(String path) {

    Cover cover = null;
    URL url = UrlBuilder.coverUrl(path);

    try {

      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)           
      url.openConnection();
      connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
      connection.connect();
      String contentType = connection.getContentType();
      FileOutput output = new FileOutput(contentType);
      OutputEncoding encoding = output.encoding;

      // create Image object from InputStream.
      InputStream imgStream = url.openStream();
      byte[] imageBytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(imgStream);
      Image image = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImage(imageBytes);

      // generated details for image path and file name.
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
      String dir = sdf.format(book.getRelease());
      String ext = output.extension;

      // save original image
      Image ogImage = resizeImage(image, encoding, image.getHeight(), 100);
      String ogPath = dir + "/" + book.getItemCode() + "." + ext;
      String ogLocation = saveImage(ogPath, ogImage);

      // save md image
      Image mdImage = resizeImage(image, encoding, MD_HEIGHT, 100);
      String mdPath = dir + "/" + book.getItemCode() + "_MD." + ext;
      String mdLocation = saveImage(mdPath, mdImage);

    } catch(IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  private static Image resizeImage(Image image, OutputEncoding encoding, int height, int quality) {

    // create output settings and set image quality.
    OutputSettings settings = new OutputSettings(encoding);
    settings.setQuality(quality);

    // Get an instance of the imagesService to transform images.
    ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();

    int width = (int) Math.floor(height * image.getWidth() / image.getHeight());

    Transform transform = ImagesServiceFactory.makeResize(width, height, false);
    Image resizedImage = imagesService.applyTransform(transform, image, settings);

    return resizedImage;

  }

  private static String saveImage(String fileName, Image image) {

    byte[] content = image.getImageData();
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

    // Modify access list to allow all users with link to read file
    List<Acl> acls = new ArrayList<>();
    acls.add(Acl.of(Acl.User.ofAllUsers(), Acl.Role.READER));

    BlobInfo info = BlobInfo.newBuilder(bucket, fileName).setAcl(acls).build();

    // the inputstream is closed by default, so we don't need to close it here
    Blob blob = storage.create(info, content);

    // return the public download link
    return blob.getMediaLink();

  }

  private static class FileOutput {

    public String extension;
    public OutputEncoding encoding;

    public FileOutput(String mimeType) {

      switch(mimeType) {
        case "image/png":
          extension = "png";
          encoding = ImagesService.OutputEncoding.PNG;
          break;
        case "image/jpeg":
        default:
          extension = "jpg";
          encoding = ImagesService.OutputEncoding.JPEG;
          break;
      }

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This was an order of operations issue. Absent from the code, I was saving out multiple sizes of the image (sm, md, lg, etc). I was processing and saving the images from smallest to largest. Reversing the order has fixed the issue.